# "external" session for a java website

Tags: java, php, wordpress, session

we have a product website (let's call it site1) that runs Java and uses sessions. any attempt to access a url directly will fail unless a user already has a valid session. 

now we'd like to add a CMS to the mix (most likely word press) and would like to be able to have links from content pages directly to the relevant product url.

question is how do we obtain a session for the java site so that a user doesn't get redirected to the login screen?

Thanks.

Comment: are they gonna be in the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

Have your Java site/code generate an encrypted string based on a key that both the Java code and the target PHP site knows.

Then, in the Java code, direct the user to a link with a _GET variable in the address containing that encrypted string.

Then, that page on the target site will use the _GET variable to determine if the user is allowed to bypass the log-in process (by decrypting the string based on the key the Java code used).

In other words:

1) Java says "loginid = 'johndoe-201111240500pm'"

2) Java then, say, encodes that variable to '4xQrSTy5' using key 'ABCDEF'

3) Java then directs user to 'http://www.testsite.com/externallogin.php?loginjava=4xQrSTy5'

4) Test Site takes _GET variable and decrypts it using key 'ABCDEF'

5) Test Site then spits the string at '-' and gets the username and the time it was generated.

6) If, say, the Test Site $loginjava variable time is within 60 seconds of the Test Site's server time, user is logged in.

Comment: well, almost. at a second glance, I'm not sure I follow. user comes to the php site (site1) and clicks on a link that takes them to the java site (site2). sessions are anonymous so no need for login. the way you laid out the steps seems like you're going in a reverse direction, no?   in any case, I think I get it.  it should work if I create a ./externalsession.jsp which will just instantiate a session, and PHP will call that first, and then the URL it wants.   makes sense?